# How to get records in Laravel 9.x belongsToMany relationship orderBy relationship existence, followed by abstinence using pagination

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

Laravel version 9.x
PHP version 8.1

Current code.

```php
    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param \App\Models\Site $site
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit(Request $request, Site $site)
    {
        $site->load(['servers' => function($query) {
            $query->select('id')->orderBy('id', 'asc');
        }]);

        $result = Server::select('id', 'name')
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->simplePaginate(config('app.limit'));

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response()->view('site.ajax.edit', compact('site', 'result'));
        }

        return response()->view('site.edit', compact('site', 'result'));
    }
```

```php
\\ app/models/Server.php
public function sites()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Site::class, 'server_site', 'server_id', 'site_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

```php
\\ app/models/Site.php
public function servers()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Server::class, 'server_site', 'site_id', 'server_id')->withTimestamps();
}
```

New business rule:
List all servers, paginated, initially bringing all servers linked to the informed site, followed by the other servers that have no relationship with the informed site or any other site. In all cases (abstinence and existence), the result must be ordered by server name.
Assume you have access to the `$site` variable to perform the query.

This the part of the code that need to be updated.

```php
    $result = Server::select('id', 'name')
    ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
    ->simplePaginate(config('app.limit'));
```

Note:
Bringing in all the results to do the sort in PHP would not be an option. The idea is to bring the result ready with the query.
I tried using `join()` and `with()` but I didn't get it. I think because of my own limitation.
If anyone has a suggestion on how to do this, I would appreciate the help.

The web page:
This is the site editing (location) page. On this screen, all servers available for relationship are listed, in a paginated manner.
What I need is to display, at the beginning of the table listing all servers, the servers that are related to the site being edited, followed by the other servers.

Exemple:
Editing Vancouver Site

```
All Servers
| Checkbox  | Server Name    |
| --------  | -------------- |
| Checked   | server bbb     |
| Checked   | server ddd     |
| Checked   | server fff     |
| unchecked | server aaa     |
| unchecked | server ccc     |
| unchecked | server ggg     |

pages 1, 2, 3, 4, etc.
```

Comment: could you please make an example with your own data? if i understood well you have a site and you want to get all the servers linked to it and then all the servers without any relation to the site you have or any other site means you want all the servers that are not associated to any site right?

Comment: @Mike These are my data. A site (location) can have multiple servers, and a server can control multiple sites (locations).
Think of it as the common case of roles and users.

Anyway, I'll edit it for an additional explanation.

Comment: yeah i understood the structure of your database, but i'm not sure about the queries you want to perform, that's why I asked for sample data

Comment: Hope it helps. Pls let me know if it is not clear or is not what u really wanted.

Comment: Yes. There is a 'site' bind... full controller action posted now.. sorry for did not post it before.

Comment: don't worry, actually you wrote about the $site variable, so yeah it was implicit.

Comment: i have other questions, so lets suppose your pagination has maximum 20 servers per page, and we have in total 15 related to your site and 10 not related, do you want the 15(related) + 5(not related) in the first page and the last 5(not related) in the second page? or do you want the not related always showing at the end of each page?

Comment: first option.... 20 perpage.. The business rule do not care about the how many are then .. the unique rule is the related shows at top... with your example, the answer is 15 related + 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```php
$result = Server::select('id', 'name')
            ->orderByDesc(
            Site::selectRaw(1)
                ->leftJoin('server_site', 'sites.id', 'server_site.site_id')
                ->whereColumn('server_site.server_id', 'servers.id')
                ->where('server_site.site_id', $site->id)
                ->union(fn ($query) => $query->selectRaw(0))
                ->limit(1)
                ->toBase()
        )
        ->orderBy('name', 'asc')
        ->simplePaginate($per_page);
```

I asked the same question on the Laracast forum and got the answer there. User Rodrigo Pedra who replied and it's working.

I post it here to multiply knowledge.

Anyway, here's the link to the conversation.

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/belongstomany-relationship-orderby-relationship-existence-followed-by-abstinence-using-pagination?page=1&replyId=778641

Answer (score 0):

According to me you have to execute the following code:

```
$maxServersPerPages = 20;
$page = \Request::input('page') ?? 1;
$relatedServers = $site->load('servers')->servers()->orderBy('name')->get();
$otherServers = Server::whereNotIn('id', $relatedServers->pluck('id'))->orderBy('name')->get();
$allServers = $relatedServers->merge($otherServers);
$currentPageServers = $allServers->forPage($page, $maxServersPerPage)
```

we get all the servers related to your site by eager loading them; then we get all the servers that are not related to your site, this means we have to exclude all those we got in the query before; we merge the servers collections we obtained by getting one collection, finally we get the servers related to the specified page paginated depending on your `$maxServerPerPage` value.

Comment: I will give it a try.
But its not the real answer for the problem, because you are doing the pagination at the php side not at database side. 
Thats why i did not posted the full method before and only the part that I need to be updated: The query that Im binding to the $result variable :)

But thx for your proposal